# Moving designs docs,views and queries from one database to another in cloudant

Tags: cloudant

I have queries/views/design docs in cloudant. I want to move them to another database. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudant/CouchDB replication will copy all of the documents (including design documents) to the target databases, as long as the user being used to authenticate against the target database has 'admin' access - because you need admin access to write a design document.

Comment: I want to copy everything except documents.

Comment: You can use filtered replication: see https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication or https://docs.cloudant.com/advanced_replication.html#filtered-replication

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way with Cloudant. If you want to write a NodeJS program, it's pretty easy. Here's a gist that deletes all documents except design docs. It could quickly be modified to copy the design docs to a different database. https://gist.github.com/rajrsingh/6044d58e2ae743d7ec5b